# How to insert data from a modal PHP Codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, forms, codeigniter, modal-dialog

I have a modal form (simple) that I want to insert in my BD, but I'm not getting the expected result

[modalview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/07IgN.png)

this is the button that calls my modal:

```
  <button type='button' class='btn btn-info'  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-default-cliente"><span class='fa fa-plus'></span></button>
```

this is my modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modal-default-cliente">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Agregar Usuario</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">

         <form  method="POST" id="clienteform">

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="nombrecompleto">Nombre Completo:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nombremodal" id="nombremodal" required="required">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
               <label for="telefono">Teléfono:</label>
               <input type="text" class="form-control" name="telefonomodal" id="telefonomodal">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
               <label for="direccion">Dirección:</label>
               <input type="text" class="form-control" name="direccionmodal" id="direccionmodal">
            </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="submit" name="action" class="btn btn-success" value="Guardar">
                </div>
            </form>          

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
            </div>
        </div>            
    </div>        
</div>
```

This is my Javascript code, which by the way the parameters of the form arrive

```
$(document).on("submit", "#clienteform", function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var nombre = $("#nombremodal").val();
    var telefono = $("#telefonomodal").val();
    var direccion = $("#direccionmodal").val();   

    $.ajax({
        url: base_url+"mantenimiento/Ventas/agregarClientemodal", 
        method:'POST',
        success: function(data){
                    alert(data);
                     $("#modal-default-cliente").modal("hide");
            }
    });

});
```

This is my action in the "Ventas" Controller:

```
public function agregarClientemodal(){

        $data = array(
            'Nombre' => $this->input->post("nombremodal") ,
            'Telefono' => $this->input->post("telefonomodal"),
            'Direccion' => $this->input->post("direccionmodal"),
            'Estado' => "1"
             );

         $this->Ventas_model->agregarClientemodal($data);           

    }
```

and finally my function in the Sales model:

```
 public function agregarUsuariomodal($data){

       return $this->db->insert("Clientes",$data);
    }
```

I'm new to Codeigniter, and when I click on my save button, my modal window does nothing

Expected behavior: save the record and hide the modal

behavior obtained: clicking on the submit does nothing

what am I doing wrong? What do I need to validate? any help for me?

Comment: Have you checked your browser's Javascript console for errors?  Have you checked your Network tab to see if the ajax request was made?  If it was made, what was the response?

Comment: First of all open console and check if any error appears on console while clicking on submit button, if not then check in xhr or network tab if your ajax request sent successfully or not...if yes then check for the parameters you sent in request and error in your xhr requests response... that's how you can to debug it.

Comment: Also check if your jQuery script tag is correctly used or defined

Comment: You said you are getting a 404. In the network console what is the URL it is going to for the Ajax request?

Comment: `url: base_url+...` Where is `base_url` defined?

Comment: Yes sir! when changing #clienteform for .clienteform ... the modal is hidden, but is not saving the data in BD, any help for me? @PatrickQ

Comment: You didn't answer any of the questions asked, so no, I have no help for you yet.

Comment: If I answered, If I have defined base_ul, also I do not have errors in my console, nor at XHR level, I guess the error is in my PHP code, what do you believe? @PatrickQ

Comment: Then you need to check error log on the server side.

Comment: if you want help you need to stop skirting around the questions asked. open dev tools go to network and see what url is being requested when you submit... what is that url? a 404 does not indicate a php issue

Answer (score 1):

**Hope this will help you :**

*Pass `form post` values with ajax's `data` using  `var formdata = $(this).serialize();`, and use `site_url()` for the URL*

Your `ajax` should be like this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#clienteform").on("submit", function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var formdata = $(this).serialize();
    $.ajax({
        url: '<?=site_url("mantenimiento/Ventas/agregarClientemodal");?>', 
        method:'POST',
        data : formdata,
        success: function(data)
        {
            alert(data);
            $("#modal-default-cliente").modal("hide");
        }
    });
  });
});
```

Your `agregarClientemodal` method should be like this :

```
public function agregarClientemodal()
{
    $data = array(
        'Nombre' => $this->input->post("nombremodal") ,
        'Telefono' => $this->input->post("telefonomodal"),
        'Direccion' => $this->input->post("direccionmodal"),
        'Estado' => "1"
         );

    $this->Ventas_model->agregarClientemodal($data);
    echo "success";
    exit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `base_url` variable is not defined in javascript/jquery.

So you need to change that line into:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '<?php echo base_url("mantenimiento/Ventas/agregarClientemodal");?>', 
    method:'POST',
    success: function(data){
                alert(data);
                 $("#modal-default-cliente").modal("hide");
        }
});
```

it will generate correct url.

Further you can check console for error logs.